# Unable to use a declared function

Tags: scala

I have a snippet of code:

```
 val inputToClassifierIndex: ConnectionIndex = new ConnectionIndex(inputLayer, unsupervisedLayer)

  n2s3.addNetworkObserver(new SynapticWeightSelectGraphRef(
    for(outputIndex <- 0 until unsupervisedLayer.shape.getNumberOfPoints) yield {
      for(inputX <- 0 until InputMnist.shape.dimensions(0)) yield {
        for(inputY <- 0 until InputMnist.shape.dimensions(1)) yield {
          val input = inputLayer.getNeuronPathAt(inputX, inputY)
          val output = unsupervisedLayer.getNeuronPathAt(outputIndex)
          inputToClassifierIndex.getConnectionsBetween(input, output).head
        }
      }
    },
    SynapticWeightSelectGraph.heatMap,
    4,
    100)
  )
```

As you can see `inputToClassifierIndex` is used in the `n2s3.addNetworkObserver`.

Now I have defined a DSL in which I am trying to define the same

`val iClassifierIndex: ConnectionIndex = new ConnectionIndex(name of my input layer, name of my output layer)`

But it is throwing error
while

```
val iClassifierIndex: (String, String) => ConnectionIndex = {(originId: String, destinationId: String) => ConnectionIndex(name of my input layer, name of my output layer)}
```

The above works fine can you please help.

Comment: What's the error? I'm trying to guess what you're looking for but this question just seems incomplete. Ideally, you'd also strip out all the stuff from your example code that doesn't somehow contribute to the problem you're seeing so that other can easier try and reproduce it.

Comment: @DennisHunziker sure I will do the necessary edits.